# Create Multipal Website in Magento

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, web

I want to create following 2 international websites in Magento

domain.com/uk/ , domain.com/us/

I have done this task by creating two sub-folders one for each website in Magento root folder, but I want to do this task without creating folders . For example what if my client want to create 18 websites. I surely don’t want to have 18 folders in my magento root.

I have read this below Magento blog

[http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup][1]

But challenge is : Create the website with slash (/) folder using the virtual host and .htaccess .

Can you please provide me solution.

Thanks